# Error: File operation not allowed. Access to route denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I am working on a project that uses Silverlight, where I want to show PDFS files of a server path, but when I start debugging my code I find the following exception:

[image]

where I generate the flow in the following code:

```html
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlElement myFrame = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("_sl_historyFrame");
            if (myFrame != null)
            {
                DirectoryInfo folderPath = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\192.168.1.216\UploadFileMobilePDF\" + transfer.IdTransfer);
                foreach (var file in folderPath.EnumerateFiles("*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("width", "1024");
                    myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("height", "768");
                    Uri uri = new Uri(folderPath + file.FullName);
                    string path = uri.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
                    myFrame.SetAttribute("src", path);
                    myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("left", "0");
                    myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("top", "50");
                    myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("visibility", "visible");
                }
            }
```

The error marks me when instantiating the `DirectoryInfo class folderPath = new DirectoryInfo ()`

I don't know if silverlight can't have permissions to server addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application likely doesn't have permission to access the files on the server you're trying to access.

Look into WindowsImpersonationContext for the most likely way around this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext?view=netframework-4.8

You'll want a class (say, "MyImpersonator") that uses WindowsImpersonationContext to log onto the server using valid credentials. There are too many details to present an entire solution, but *using* the class (defined elsewhere) to get a single file might look something like this:

```
     using (var impersonator = new MyImpersonator())
     {
        string name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"];
        string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pass"];


        if (impersonator.LogOnCrossDomain(account, pass))
        {                   
             if (File.Exists(filepath))
             {                           
                 byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);                          
             }
         }  
      }
```